# realtime redirecting stdout to file in linux c

Tags: c, linux, fork, dup2

I am trying to implement following bash line in c.

```
while true; do echo Hello; done > out.log
```

I can collect log in log file .

But logs are written only when executable finishes execution.

my test case which uses non exiting executable fails.

how do I write log file realtime ?

here is hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
//      while(1){
        for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
                printf("Hello World\n");
                sleep(1);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

here is helloExec.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
        char *cmd[] = {"./hello", NULL};
        int fd = -1;
        if(fork() == 0){
                fd=open("log.out", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0666);
                dup2(fd,1);
                execv(cmd[0],cmd);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

compiled with `make hello` and `make helloExec`

When I use for loop I do see logs collected after 10 sec.
Whereas If while is used then logs are not written to file.

using `tail -f log.out` to follow log file.

Any inputs about this are welcome.

NOTE: unsuccessful trying to resolve this using pipe.

Comment: Did you try to `fflush(stdout)`?

Comment: Alternatively, did you try to set `stdout` to unbuffered mode?

Comment: @dimich fflush will not work as flushing stdout before exec will not matter.
And exec will only return after completion of execution. hence it will not work and just to e sure I have tried it and sadly it didn't work.

Comment: @Devidas I mean fflush() in hello.c after printf().

Comment: @thebusybee I have tried 
``` setvbuf(stdout,NULL, _IONBF, 0); ```
before and after dup2 it didn't work.

Comment: @dimich surprisingly it worked.

can you answer below.

Comment: Although this worked I was expecting solution but would like to know if there is no way to control it from helloExec rather than hello

Comment: Why should a calling process be able to influence the inner working of another called process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piped output is buffered even aggressively than line-buffered terminal output, `\n` is not enough to flush it.
Use `fflush(stdout)` after `printf()`